# Cambodian visa extension for children

Tags: children, visa-extensions, cambodia, lithuanian-citizens

I am planning on staying in Cambodia for some time with my family (4 persons, 2 kids all Lithuanians, ie EU citizens).

I will be flying to Bangkok first (staying there 2-3 months) and then to Cambodia (Phnom Penh). Upon landing I am planning on first getting E-class 30-day visas for everyone (35$ x 4 = 140$), and then extend them for 6 months (or a year).

Before 01/09/2016 children under 12 were getting visa for free, but now it's 35$.

I have checked extensions (a one-month extension costs 35 US$, three months 65 US$, six months 125 US$, and one year 200 US$). I couldn't find anything about extensions for children.

**Do I need to pay for children's visa extensions or is it for adults only?**

Comment: Visa rules for adults and children are now the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of an answer, from a comment by @Tom:

> Visa rules for adults and children are now the same.